# How can I solve the problem with visualisation?

Tags: python, data-science, google-colaboratory

I need to display images using heat camera, but it does not work as it should. I have tried changing code. Unfortunately without a result. 
I get that error:

> ValueError: `array1` and `array2` must have the same shapes

in this line: `plt.imshow(overlay(cm.jet(grads)[:,:,:3], images[i]/255))`

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(1,10):
    plt.subplot(3,3,i)
    plt.title(examined_feature if labels[len(labels) - i]==1 else '~'+examined_feature)
    grads = visualize_cam(model_vis, -1, filter_indices=int(labels[[len(labels) - i]]), 
                          seed_input=images[len(labels) - i], backprop_modifier='guided')    
    plt.imshow(overlay(cm.jet(grads)[:,:,:3], images[len(labels) - i]/255)) # <- ValueError
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `cm.jet(grads)[:,:,:3]` has a diffent size than `images[len(labels) - i]/255`

Have you tried:

```
plt.imshow(cm.jet(grads)[:,:,:3])
plt.imshow(images[len(labels) - i]/255)
plt.show()
```

?

Comment: I've tried your version, but I've got a new error in line: plt.imshow(cm.jet(grads)[:,:,:3]), saying: TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data